# rise over run slope calculator that outputs to feet and inches

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write a rise over run calculator that can function as a construction calculator. I am receiving input in feet and inches and I output the slope in feet and inches to the nearest 1/16th.

What I have now can take an input in inches, convert it into a decimal, and output the slope in the same format.

```
import sys
while (1):
    print ("Enter the rise and run in inches to calculate slope.")
    a = (input("First measurement is:  "))
    if (a == "stop"):
         print ("goodbye")
         sys.exit()
    a=  float (a)**2  
    b = float (input("second measurement is:  "))**2
    c = (float (a) + float (b))**(1/2)
    print ("Slope is:", c,("inches"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the starting code for a solution. What it does is calculates the slope then rounds. I think what you have is trying to use the Pythagorean theorem in some way, but it can be done much simpler by doing (deltaY) / (deltaX), or rise/run.

The rounding is done by multiplying the current value by 16, rounding to the nearest integer, then dividing by 16 again. Why this works is because of how fractions convert to decimals. If you multiply and you get an integer, then you know that you got a multiple of 1/16. If not, you need to round. The way to round is to go to the nearest 1/16 value. This is done normally by going seeing between which two values the number to round resides. If it is halfway to the higher number, you round to that, otherwise you round to the lower number. This does this principle, but instead of checking between which two it is between, it only checks the numerator essentially.

For example, if you have 5/32, that number is between 2/16 and 3/16. 5/32 * 16 is 5/2 or 2.5. 2.5 is closer to 3 so we round the value to that. Then we divide the answer by 16 to get 3/16 as the final result.

One more thing, it seems you were using sys.exit() to reach the end of the function. This can be done more easily by simply breaking out of the while loop using "break."

A final thing, the state the program is in now does not check for a vertical line (if the bottom measurement is 0). I am not sure if this is a requirement, but you might have to check for that. In addition, I assumed that the rise is inputted first, then the run, making a = rise and b = run.

```
import math

def round1_16th(n):
    n *= 16
    n = round(n)
    return n/16

while (1): 
    print ("Enter the rise and run in inches to calculate slope.") 
    a = (input("First measurement is: ")) 
    if (a == "stop"): 
        print ("goodbye") 
        break
    a= float (a)
    b = float (input("second measurement is: "))
    hyp = math.sqrt(a*a + b*b)
    hypInt = int(hyp)
    hypDec = hyp - hypInt
    numerator = round(hypDec*16)
    if hypInt == 0:
        hypInt = ""
    print ("Slope is:", round1_16th(hyp),"or",hypInt,str(numerator)+"/16th")
```

Comment: Something I don't understand is how to separate a number with a decimal and output slope as integers and fraction. for example, rise(12") over run (15") = 19.20937 or  19 3/16th

Comment: The integer value of a decimal value is easy to get, just use the int(val) conversion. The whole value for a number is the integer part + decimal part. If you rearrage, decimal part is the whole decimal number - integer part.

For example, 19.20937 = 19 + 0.20937. 
This means that 0.20937 = 19.20937 - 19. 

What you can round is just the decimal part to get the 3/16th.
Does this make sense?

Comment: After you round, you know that the value of the decimal part is a multiple of 1/16th, which means that you can multiply by 16 to get the value of the numerator. Additionally, if you want to reduce the fraction to lowest terms, you can divide by the greatest common denominator (or gcd). You can see how the gcd works here: https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~greenfie/gs2004/euclid.html

Comment: Can you show a example of how that is implemented? How the return (19.20937) can be separated into (19.) and (0.20937)? from there I believe I can write it to round to the 1/16th and output as a fraction to 19 3/16 inches

Comment: The edited solution has the implementation. An issue is that it doesn't check if the slope is less than 0. For example, for rise=12 and run=15, it outputs 0 13/16th. The reducing thing still applies.

Comment: Thank you so much, the reason its giving the 0. 13/16th output is the mathmatical formula you used, if you:

Comment: a= float (a)**2
    b = float (input("second measurement is: "))**2
    slope = (a+b)**(1/2)

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to get the slope of the line. Instead, it was the hypotenuse of the triangle. That makes for sense of why you were using the formula. :P. Another option, instead of (a+b)**0.5, you can import math and use math.sqrt(a+b). It might be a bit more clear

Comment: Edited the program to do the hypotenuse instead